# EF: Delete record failed due to foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have `insteadOfDelete` triggers on my tables. Foreign Key Constraints are taken care of in `InsteadOfDelete` trigger. Since `InsteadOfDelete` trigger is present, `Cascade Delete` is removed.

This means EF is unaware that I am taking care of Foreign Key Constraint outside of the Entity Frameworks' scope. Whenever, I try to delete a row from a table whose Primary Key is referenced by other tables I get an error saying one of the `foreign key property is non-nullable`.

Is there a way to delete a record through `LINQ` without facing issues with Foreign Key Constraint?

Please note: `InsteadOfDelete` is used to solve multiple cascade path issue. More [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2733/solving-the-sql-server-multiple-cascade-path-issue-with-a-trigger/).

Comment: You can configure an association as cascaded delete in the EF conceptual model (class model). EF will rely on the db to take care of cascades, no matter how the db achieves that.

Comment: @GertArnold Can you please give an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20202114/861716

Comment: @GertArnold This is what I did. `db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM Some_tb WHERE Id = " + some_var);` Seems like the best option to me, what do you think?

Comment: Well, it hasn't got anything to do with what I said so far. And I only see a delete statement, no idea what for, when and how it is applied. I thought that in your question you were referring to delete through EF's DbSets. Give more details.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to delete through EF's DBSets without EF checking for Foreign constraints. However, the solution to this, need a lot of extra code to be written. It seems to me Executing a SQL command is best way to avoid these work arounds.

Answer (score 1):

In Entity Frame work you can set Foreign Key as `Allow Null` and when you want Delete Rows , you should set Row's Foreign Key =`null`.
Consider the following model :

```
    public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId {get; set;}
    public Employee Employee {get;set;}
}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId {get; set;}
    public string EmployeeName {get;set;}
}
```

for deleting rows with `foreign key` you can :
1:

```
context.Entry(Project).Reference(r => r.Employee).CurrentValue = null;
```

2:

```
    public void RemoveEmployeeFromProject(int projectId)
{
    var project = Context.Projects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProjectId == projectId);
    project.EmployeeId = (int?)null;
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: This may work. However, there is one issue, lets say the Project table's Primary Key is referenced by many tables. then it would be tedious, isn't it?

Comment: I ended up using custom SQL query