# Entity Framework is trying to insert into wrong table?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I've built a test application with Entity Framework to simulate a database that contains friends lists.

I want the database to store the user's ID's and when I retrieve them (the "AcceptedFriends") I want Entity Framework to also return the friends "usermodel".

But every time I try to add 2 users as friends to the "AcceptedFriends" table it 
throws an exception:

" **Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Users'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Users'. The duplicate key value is (GUID value of a user's ID)** "

Some attempted solutions:

1. [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896503/how-should-i-model-friendships-between-users-with-ef-code-first)
2. Attempting to create 2 lists of the same friend list (received, sent) but that defeats the purpose of what I am trying to achieve.
3. [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201468/whats-the-simplest-approach-to-friends-list-in-ef)

Here are the code files:

**"Users Model"**

```
 public class Users
 {

    #region Private fields

    #endregion


    #region Public properties

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }


    public virtual List<AcceptedFriends> AcceptedFriendsList { get; set; }

    // public virtual List<PendingFriends> PendingFriendsList { get; set; }

    // public virtual  List<RemovedFriends> RemovedFriendsList { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

**"Accepted Friends model"**

```
    public class AcceptedFriends
    {
        #region Public properties

        public string RelationKey { get; set; }

        public string RequestSenderID { get; set; }

        public string RequestReceiverID { get; set; }


        public virtual List<Messages> ChatList { get; set; }


        public Users RequestSender { get; set; }

        public Users RequestReceiver { get; set; }

        #endregion
     }
```

**"Database model creation"**

```
        #region Users table

        // Create primary key in Users table
        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>().HasKey(property => property.ID);

        // Map Username to be unique
        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>().HasIndex(property => property.Username).IsUnique();

        // Create a one to many relation with AcceptedFriends table
        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>()
            .HasMany(property => property.AcceptedFriendsList)
            .WithOne(property => property.RequestReceiver)
            .HasForeignKey(property => property.RequestReceiverID);


        #endregion


        #region Accepted friends table

        // Create key for AcceptedFriends
        modelBuilder.Entity<AcceptedFriends>().HasKey(property => property.RelationKey);

        #endregion
```

**Edit**

Here is how I am inserting the friends

```
public static void AddFriends(AcceptedFriends friends)
{
    using(Context context = ConnectToDatabase())
    {
        context.AcceptedFriends.Add(friends);

        context.SaveChanges();
    };
 }
```

**Edit 2**

Here is where I add the friends/users

Plus I've noticed another odd behaviour When I add new users to the friends table 
 without adding them to the users table first it adds them both to the friends table and users table.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to database");

        DB.ConnectToDatabase();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to database successfully");

        List<Users> userList = new List<Users>(DB.GetUsersList());

        List<AcceptedFriends> friendsCount = new List<AcceptedFriends>(DB.GetAcceptedFriends());


        if(userList.Count != 2)
        {
            DB.AddUser(new Users()
            {
                Username = "User1",
                PasswordHash = "PasswordHash",
            });

            DB.AddUser(new Users()
            {
                Username = "User2",
                PasswordHash = "PasswordHash",
            });

            userList = new List<Users>(DB.GetUsersList());
        };


        if(friendsCount.Count < 1)
        {
            Users user1 = userList[0];
            Users user2 = userList[1];

            DB.AddFriends(new AcceptedFriends()
            {
                RequestReceiver = user2,

                RequestSender = user1,
            });
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Server is great success!");

        Console.ReadLine();
```

**Edit 3**

I might have found a solution. 
It does return the models both for the user and friends,
But I can't accept this as a solution yet because it feels to hackey(?) for me

(Thanks to @wertzui, You helped me to get to this solution)

Basically everytime a new context is created it sets up the the friends and users to return thier usermodels

```
/// <summary>
    /// Gets the friends user models
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"> The database context that was created </param>
    private static void SetupFriends(Context context)
    {
        // For every "AcceptedFriend"
        foreach(AcceptedFriends friend in context.AcceptedFriends)
        {
            // Get sender and receiver usermodels 
            // by matching ID's
            Users sender = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.ID == friend.RequestSenderID);
            Users receiver = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(user => user.ID == friend.RequestReceiverID);

            sender.AcceptedFriendsList.Add(friend);
            receiver.AcceptedFriendsList.Add(friend);

            friend.RequestSender = sender;
            friend.RequestReceiver = receiver;
        };
    }
```

Comment: Please share how your `friends`-variable is being created/populated

Comment: Added. Please take another look

Comment: Just now realized what you meant.  `friends` is a parameter I use to pass a friend model

Answer (score 0):

When you create new User Instances in your `new AcceptFriends {...}` Code, you are not setting their `Id`, so they keep their default which is `0`. Now Entity Framework thinks, that you want to create a new Friendship with 2 new Users. Instead you should populate them with the Users, you created earlier.

```
if(friendsCount.Count < 1)
{
    Users user1 = userList[0];
    Users user2 = userList[1];

    DB.AddFriends(new AcceptedFriends()
    {
        RequestReceiver = user1,
        RequestSender = user2,
    });
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion but it didn't work, Btw after further testing it would appear that Entity Framework *Does* add the ID's automatically. Might there be an "error" in the way I am trying to map the User's with the friends table ?

Comment: Try setting RequestReceiverId and RequestSenderId instead of the objects.

Comment: Attempted. It adds them yes, But it defeats the purpose of what I am trying to achieve because it doesn't load the 'friends' 'user' models.